# Как перемещать приложение, если шапка с кнопками управления окна (закрыть/свернуть/расширить) скрыта

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Как скрыть верхнюю шапку где находятся кнопки управления приложения
(закрыть/свернуть/расширить), но в тоже время можно было бы перемещать приложение.

Как саму шапку скрыть я понял, но как сделать чтобы можно было бы при этом перемещать приложение

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
w.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: вот [пример кода, который один текст выводит (невидимое окно)](https://gist.github.com/zed/62227e5e360fd2a5316c74af9497f42b). Вот [пример, который рисует по нажатию мышки](https://gist.github.com/zed/d1b63f81896e091b30b2f83e3ec6c1f1) -- вы можете попробовать перемещать окно вместо рисования `self.move(self.point)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a187e635f4e257eb7a913f1dd25be07b88ad78eb/pyqt__mouse_manual_move__FramelessWindowHint.py)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.old_pos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: нужно сбрасывать `self.old_pos`, когда мышь отпускают, иначе и правой кнопкой можно возить. [Пример (только левой перемещать можно)](https://gist.github.com/zed/77e705caa840bab117057952f9ca6191)

Comment: лучше, только возможно не хватает ещё `if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:` в `mouseReleaseEvent()` (чтобы нажатие правой кнопки мыши, не влияло на таскание левой кнопкой).

Comment: хммм......... )

Answer (score 0):

Принцип простой. Тебе надо отследить нажатие левой кнопки мыши на любом элементе, хоть на всей форме. Сохранить координаты. Далее отслеживать движение мыши, брать ее координаты относительно всего экрана, вычесть из них сохраненные координаты, и установить позицию формы в получившиеся координаты. Ничего сложного тут нет.